# Flight Simulator X change controls behavior

Tags: keyboard, flight-simulator-x

I'm trying to play Microsoft's Flight Simulator X, but currently i'm having a bad time, as I'm used to flight games where when you unpress a key, the control surface returns to its initial position. On FSX, it keeps in the same state. Wether that's realistic or not is not the problem, is there just a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Simplest solution is probably to use a gamepad or joystick if you have one.

Comment: @MBraedley nope, buying a joystick is not an option for me

Answer (score -1):

Go into controls and assign a key, or use the mouse yoke. Press  Ctrl-Y to activate the mouse yoke